# Netbeans binding

Tags: java, netbeans, binding, jtable

I'm trying to bind a table from my db in a `Jtable` in my desktop app.
I had follow the step in this guide:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html
and everything is fine, but I can't change the query to show the data in a different order. 
If I try to change the query the application does not work. 
Netbeans had create the query so:

```
SELECT t FROM TbAzioni t
```

my table name is `tb_azioni` and I would like to have a query like this:

```
select * from tb_azioni order by azcodaz
```

but if I change the query nothing works. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Go to the JTable properties in NetBeans and enable: autoCreateRowSorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Vector get()throws Exception
{
Vector<Vector<String>> vector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select * from tb_azioni order by azcodaz");
ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
Vector<String> s = new Vector<String>();
s.add(rs.getString(4)); 
s.add(rs.getString(5)); 
s.add(rs.getString(6)); 
s.add(rs.getString(1)); 
s.add(rs.getString(7)); 
vector.add(s);

}
/*Close the connection after use (MUST)*/
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();

return vector;
}

 private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
 private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header


  data = get();
        JTable table5=new JTable(data,header);
        for(int i2=0;i2<table5.getRowCount();i2++){
        Object[] d={data.get(i2).get(0),data.get(i2).get(1),data.get(i2).get(2),data.get(i2).get(3),data.get(i2).get(4)};
        model.addRow(d);
        }

DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
JTable table=new JTable(model);
```